# How to map state to props in redux in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hi I am reading this tutorial https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-get-started-redux-react-native where guy explained about use case of `redux` in react native application. Well, I gotcha things there, but I see that

`userReducers` is not defined there in class Login.js I am not sure where it is being referenced.

Can anyone help me what is that ? Shouldn't it `state.user` instead `user.userReducers.user`

[image]

Comment: It's probably worth reading the rest of the article because I believe it fills in some missing holes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your index.ios.js file while creating the redux store, you are name-spacing this data under `userReducers`.

[image: take a look at line 10 where you are creating the store with the reducers.]

According to line 10 where you are creating the store, all state variables added by `userReducers` will be available under `state.userReducers`.

Comment: Well. It is defining variable in `index.ios.js` and can we access it in `Login.js` ? without export ?

Comment: In your login component, you are mapping that state variable to props. All data in `stata.userReducers.user` will be available as `this.props.user`

Comment: hmm I meant that writer defined variable `userReducers` in `index.ios.js` like `var userReducers = ...` and using it in `Login.js` like this `state.userReducers.user` Is it possible to access `userReducers` variable in other file than `index.ios.js` as this was not exported

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on my last comment ?

Comment: you can access the state userReducers in any other file or component as long you connect it to the redux state. Just like your last line in the `Login.js`.